# How does FAST ESP work in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: fast-search, search

When we install FAST ESP, does it replace SharePoint 2010's search engine feature? If not then how exactly does it work with SP 2010 search engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I still want to spend some more time diving deeper into, but you have the ability to configure both FAST and regular SharePoint Search Service Applications on the same farm.  You can configure the mapping at the Web Application level, though I'm not sure if you can support both SharePoint Search and FAST Search on the same Web Application.

I have looked at a couple of client scenarios where only certain sets of content would require FAST, so a hybrid approach was proposed at the farm level, but individual Web Applications would use a specific tool.

Comment: Also if you spent $$$ on a FAST license, which isnt exactly cheap, why would you need the office search?

Comment: Since FAST comes with SharePoint Server Enterprise those customers have a choice.  FAST is so dramatically different than "regular" search and I think the level of effort to configure and maintain it is much higher when you start using things like the extraction engine.  In a large organization with fundamentally different types of content it might be a good idea to match up the right tool for the right content.

Comment: FAST is not coming with SharePoint Enterprise! The options to configure are available, but you have to license the FAST servers. Just to make clear. FAST is not installed on the shharepoint servers. For production it will require dedicated boxes. If you want scale and redundancy you will quickly end up spending a lots of $$$ as Anders Rask mentions. SharePoint Enterpprise != FAST Search for ShharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I have done this - see my blog on how to do it  :-

http://blog.njpenterprises.com/archive/2010/05/23/getting-fast-esp-5-3-3-working-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Regards

Nigel